# nvme to sata adapter

Tags: ssd, sata, adapter, nvme, m.2

Is there a m.2 nvme to sata 2.5" adapter? Or hasn't it been invented yet?
I have an nvme SSD left over and I have a notebook that needs an SSD so I'd like to avoid buying another one.
It is obvious that the speed would be reduced to that of the SATA interface but this is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - No, I don't think so, and there may never be (but I'd love to be proved incorrect).

---

I looked into this, extensively, earlier this year, and ended up scrapping the idea and buying a M.2 SATA. I wrote about it on my blog (link in my profile), but it is rather rambling and long winded.

The best summary of the situation is in [this post](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/m-2-nvme-to-sata-adapter.3322637/post-20288778) on Tom's Hardware

> If they're M.2 NVMe not M.2 SATA. I don't think such an adapter
> exists. It likely isn't possible. At least without a lot of expensive
> hardware to convert.
>
> Startech just released an M.2 NVMe to USB 3.1 Gen 2 enlosure.
> Everything else external, I believe, requires Thunderbolt. If you want
> full speed anything other than Thunderbolt 3 enclosures are pointless.
> Well Thunderbolt 2 may be good enough but hardly any PCs have those
> and I believe all the Thunderbolt NVMe enclosures are Thunderbolt 3
> and I don't think anyone makes an adapter to go from a Thunderbolt 3
> peripheral to Thunderbolt 1/2 computer.
> [https://www.startech.com/HDD/Enclosures/usb-c-m2-drive-enclosure~SM21BMU31C3](https://www.startech.com/HDD/Enclosures/usb-c-m2-drive-enclosure%7ESM21BMU31C3)
>
> They do may an M.2 to SATA adapter. NVMe is not supported. Just M.2
> SATA models.
> [https://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/M-2-SSD-2-5-in-SATA-Adapter~SAT32M225](https://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/M-2-SSD-2-5-in-SATA-Adapter%7ESAT32M225)

I found it remarkable that there wasn't such an adapter/enclosure available, but as the quote above states, *apparently* the hardware required makes the whole endeavour not worthwhile.

There are however, dual mode USB 3.1 enclosures that support M.2 SATA/NGFF and NVMe/PCIe (I bought a few at the same time as I got the 2.5" M.2 SATA to SATA enclosure), but that obviously doesn't help your 2.5" form factor requirement.